# Adding additional arguments to overridden functions without pylint complaining

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, mypy

I would like to define a function `f` in a superclass that has a set of required positional arguments, and permit subclasses to provide their own versions of `f` that share the required arguments, but also have additional named arguments.

Further, I want to do this in such a way that mypy is able to check the types of everything, and pylint3 doesn't complain about anything.

Functions `f` and `g` below represent my best attempts thus far:

```py
from typing import Any

class Base:
    def f(self, required_arg: int, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        print(self, required_arg, args, kwargs)
    
    def g(self, required_arg: int, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        print(self, required_arg, kwargs)

class A(Base):
    def f(self, required_arg: int, x: int = 42, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        print(self, required_arg, x, args, kwargs)
    
    def g(self, required_arg: int, *, x: int = 42, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        print(self, required_arg, x, kwargs)
```

This code works as expected (passing `x=20` places it in `kwargs` for the base class, and `x` for the derived class), however running pylint3 yields the following warnings:

```
W: 11, 1: Keyword argument before variable positional arguments list in the definition of f function (keyword-arg-before-vararg)
W: 11, 1: Parameters differ from overridden 'f' method (arguments-differ)
W: 14, 1: Parameters differ from overridden 'g' method (arguments-differ)
```

There are, of course, a variety of ways to suppress that class of warning, either generally, by file, or by line, but I would like to declare the function in such a way that this is not necessary.

If it makes a difference, I don't actually care if the base class can *access* any of the additional arguments; `kwargs` is just part of the declaration so as to permit it to take arbitrary arguments.  Additionally, it is acceptable to require that `x` be *passed* as a keyword argument, as long as it ends up in `x` and not `kwargs['x']`.

Comment: Be aware that MyPy is basically telling you that your inheritance scheme is broken. Inheritance means that an ``A`` can be used in place of a ``Base`` – which both ``f`` and ``g`` violate. For example, ``Base().f(1, 2, x=3)`` is valid but ``A().f(1, 2, x=3)`` will fail due to passing ``x`` twice. If the base does not need the variadic arguments, it should not take them in the first place.

Comment: "``kwargs`` is just part of the declaration so as to permit it to take arbitrary arguments." – Is this because ``Base`` *needs* to take arbitrary arguments, or because you *think it should* take these as its subclass does as well?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Mypy isn't complaining about anything at the moment; I mentioned it because *keeping* mypy happy is a constraint. The warnings are coming from pylint. Base will never be constructed directly. It exists only to define an interface and common supertype for mypy, and to provide defaults for functions not defined by the subclasses. I added kwargs because I will be calling `foo.f(1, x=2)` on `foo`s declared as Base, and without kwargs, mypy will (rightly) issue a warning. (continued...)

Comment: (...continued)  w.r.t. your `A().f(1, 2, x=3)` example: if there is a way to declare `f` such that `x` *must* be passed as a keyword rather than positional argument (s.t. `f(1,2 x=3)` is illegal for both Base and A, and `f(1,x=3)` is legal for both), that would satisfy my requirements.

Comment: So to answer your question directly: Actual `Base` objects need not take arbitrary arguments, but variables *declared* as `Base` but *pointing to* an object that is a subclass of `Base` *do* need to be able to take arbitrary keyword arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have parameters in the child class which don't feature in the parent class, so long as they are optional. This would be easiest without args and kwargs.

```
class Animal:
    def speak(self, volume: int) -> None:
        print(f"Animal speaking at volume {volume}")
        
class Parrot(Animal):
    def speak(self, volume: int, words: str ="Pretty Polly") -> None:
        print(f"Parrot says {words} at volume {volume}")
        
a = Animal()
a.speak(4)
p = Parrot()
p.speak(5) # fine, words takes the default as "Pretty Polly"
p.speak(6, "Bye") # Fine, words works from its position
p.speak(7, optional_arg="Yay") # Fine, words can be named
```

MyPy is happy with that. **The basic rule you need to follow is that your child objects can be used as parent objects**. In this case MyPy is happy is that a `Parrot` is still a valid `Animal` because it's still possible to call `p.speak` with just `volume`, like `Animal` requires.

You can do the same thing with a keyword only argument.

```
class Parrot(Animal):
    def speak(self, required_arg: int, *, optional_kwarg: str = "Hello again") -> None:
        print(f"A {required_arg} {optional_arg}")

p = P()
p.speak(8) # Fine, as required by base class Animal
p.speak(9, optional_kwarg="Bye again") # fine, as specially allowed of Parrots
p.speak(10, "Oops") # This one won't work, because there isn't a positional argument to put it in.
```

**This is often all that you need**. When you know that you have a Parrot, you can tell it what to say. If all you know is that you have some sort of Animal, because it might be a dog and dogs can't speak English [citation needed], you should restrict yourself to instructions that all animals can handle.

---

It is possible to get your base class using `*args` and `**kwargs`. You can use the positional only argument marker `/`. The cost of doing so is that you commit things to either being a positional argument or a keyword argument. The syntax goes something like this:

```
class Base:
    def f(self, required_pos_arg: int, /, *args, required_kwarg, **kwargs) -> None:
        print(f"Base {required_pos_arg} {required_kwarg} {args} {kwargs}")
        
class A(Base):
    def f(self, required_pos_arg: int, optional_pos_arg: float=1.2, /, *args, required_kwarg, optional_kwarg: str ="Hello", **kwargs) -> None:
        print(f"A {required_pos_arg} {optional_pos_arg} {optional_kwarg} {args} {kwargs}")

b = Base()
b.f(9, 0.2, "Additional_pos_arg", required_kwarg="bar", optional_kwarg="Foo", kwarg_member="Additional_kw_arg")

a = A()
a.f(9, 0.2, "Additional_pos_arg", required_kwarg="bar", optional_kwarg="Foo", kwarg_member="Additional_kw_arg")
```

By using the `/` marker at the end of the positional ones, and `*` (or `*args`) before the start of the keyword ones, you remove the ambiguity that comes from confusing positional and keyword arguments. You can add more positional arguments (again, they must be optional so that the bare bones call still works) to the end of list before `*`. You can add more keyword arguments (same restrictions) after the `*`. You'll note that the child class must also take `args` and `kwargs` because the child must accept anything the parent would. And then MyPy is happy again.

---

However, as I mentioned earlier, this is probably not what you want to do.

The fundamental purpose of using MyPy is to get the computer to help your ensure that you're only using things where they make sense. If you add `*args` and `**kwargs` you necessarily limit how good a job it can do. It's no longer able to stop you from asking the dog to recite Macbeth, or even to stop you from asking the Parrot to speak with `florgle` of 9.6.

Except in very specific circumstances where you really want the base class to handle everything, it is safer to restrict yourself to what you actually want to do.

You will of course then find that if you write this code

```
def EnglishTest(students: List[Animal]):
    for s in students:
        s.speak(5, words="Double, double toil and trouble")
```

MyPy will yell at you. That's not a bug. It's doing its job. It's telling you that most animals don't do words. And it prompts you to write instead

```
def EnglishTest(students: List[Animal]):
    for s in students:
        if isinstance(s, Parrot):
            s.speak(5, words="Double, double toil and trouble")
        else:
            print(f"{s} failed its English test.")
```

Comment: The `/` marker did the trick. What version of python introduced that, and where can I find it in the docs? You are correct that mypy is generally right to warn about passing `words` to Animal.speak. But in this particular case, I'm doing some weird things that are (probably) beyond mypy's ability to statically analyze, and prefer false negatives to false positives (again, in this *particular* case). So adding `**kwargs` to the base function *is* probably necessary.

Comment: It was 3.8, introduced in PEP 570 
(https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter)
(https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/)